# Server to Server Authentication and API communication with Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a usecase to call CRM APIs from my Nodejs client with non-interactive login. For this I have a client key and secret generated after registering my App on Azure Active Directory. I am successful in generating access token, but anytime I attempt to access data (via a Microsoft OData client or straight Web API HTTP requests), I always receive a 401, despite the inclusion of my access token in the authorization header. Here is my Nodejs client:

```js
var adal = require('adal-node');
var azure = require('azure');
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();


var AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com';
var tenant = 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var clientId = 'xxxx';
var clientSecret = 'xxxx'
var resource = 'https://xxxx.crm.dynamics.com';

var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

var accessToken;
var credentials;

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log("======================SUCCESS=======================");

    accessToken=tokenResponse.accessToken;

  console.log(accessToken);
  }
});

app.get('/accounts', function(req, res) {

var token = "Bearer " + accessToken;
console.log(token);

var options = {
  host: 'xxxx.crm.dynamics.com',
  path: '/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name,address1_city&$top=10',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'OData-MaxVersion':'4.0',
    'OData-Version':'4.0'
  }
};

callback = function(response) {
    console.log("Callback Invoked");
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
    console.log("Data ====>"+str);
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
      console.log("Complete Data ====>"+str);
    console.log(str);
  });
}

console.log(options);
https.request(options, callback).end();  

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Did you configure the delegation permission to CRM in the AAD application? Does the user that you're using have an assigned security role in CRM?

Comment: @FedericoJousset I am able to access APIs with the same user with interactive login. Only programmatic access is giving "Access Denied" error. Also, I have configured delete permission for "Dynamics CRM Online" and "Windows Azure Active Directory".
Thanks.

Comment: I mean delegate* permission.